# How to position image1 on right top of the image2 in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i achieve a layout with 2 images in android, one image overlaying another image at the top right?

[an image overlapping another image at the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2FZC.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ltkk.jpg
I tried using relative layout, but i could position the overlay image by giving layout margin, but if i do that i cant support all screen sizes with that design.
and also i couldnt position the overlay image with respect to the underimage.
i want to design my layout like the pic i have shared.

Comment: What have you tried? You can use relative layout to achieve image overlay. We can help but only if there's some effort from your part.

Comment: can you give example n tell what excatly you want?

Comment: post ur desired image..or xml what u tried...

Answer (score 1):

I could get this working from the below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addnewcustomer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/c1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/c1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/hover1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try look at [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). It will do the job.

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/frame-layout-in-androis.html